# Algorithm for comparing/matching all elements with one another both ways

Tags: algorithm, comparison

What is the neatest algorithm for that ? Can it be done without helping/static variable ?

Comment: What should this algorithm do? As far as I can see it only increments "tested" up until ints.length and does never call match(..)

Comment: isnt `tested` same as `i`. I that case will the `while` ever complete?

Comment: @radiospiel, ups you're right :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two "for" loops. Assuming that you don't need to compare elements against themselves, and you only need to test each pair one way around rather than both ways:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ints.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        match(ints[i], ints[j]);
    }
}
```

If you want all pairs both ways, just change `j < i` to `j < ints.length`. If you want pairs both ways, excluding self-comparisons, either add `if (i != j)` in the inner loop or else do one inner loop from 0 to `i-1`, and another from `i+1` to `ints.length`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I was using nested loop only for multidimensional arrays, I totally excluded that for this.